# Second Order Homogenous Differential Equation, given y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so, i have been given the equation:

$y''+(1/x)y'+(1-(1/4x^2))y = f(x)$

and been told to verify that

$y1(x) = x^{-1/2} sin(x)$    is one solution to the homogeneous part of the equation ($f(x)=0$)

so what I have done is differentiate $y1$ to get $y'$ and $y''$, then substituted $y,y'$ and $y''$ into my equation hoping i would get $0$ to say that it is a solution however I dont get $0$, checked multiple times, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't get zero either. Recheck the DEQ and $y_1(x)$.

Comment: y'' + (1/x)y'+(1-(1/(4x^2))y = f(x)

Comment: y1(x) = x^(-1/2) sin(X)

Comment: You just discovered the issue! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed out a factor of $\color{red}{y}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
y &=& \frac{\sin x}{x^{1/2}} \\
y' &=& \frac{\cos x}{x^{1/2}} - \frac{\sin x}{2x^{3/2}} \\
y'' &=& \frac{-\sin x}{x^{1/2}} - \frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}} + \frac{3 \sin x}{4x^{3/2}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute this into the eqution
\begin{eqnarray*}
y''  + \frac{1}{x}y' +\left(1-\frac{1}{4x^2} \right) \color{red}{y}= ... \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: sorry, my fault, that was a typo, so i am doing it correctly because that was what i was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous second-order linear differential equation for which $x^{-1/2} \sin(x)$ is a solution is not quite what you wrote:
$$ y'' + \frac{y'}{x} + \left(1 - \frac{1}{4x^2}\right) y = 0$$

EDIT:
$$ \eqalign{y &= x^{-1/2} \sin(x)\cr
            y' &= x^{-1/2} \cos(x) - \frac{1}{2} x^{-3/2} \sin(x)\cr
            y'' &= - x^{-1/2} \sin(x) - x^{-3/2} \cos(x) + \frac{3}{4} x^{-5/2} \sin(x)\cr}$$
and it should all work out.

Comment: i know it is a solution i am just unsure what i am doing in my working, would appreciate a point in the right direction

Comment: So what do you get instead of $0$?

Comment: going to try again now, must have just slipped up, really appreciate the help!

Comment: ok, thank you, got it! must have just made a small error somewhere!